# Avoid using a subquery in a table join

Tags: mysql, left-join

In a MySQL 5.7 database, I have the following `User` table:

| Name | Id |
| --- | --- |
| David | 1 |
| Frank | 2 |

And the following `Order` table:

| Id | Price | UserId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 55 | 1 |
| 2 | 68 | 1 |
| 3 | 50 | 1 |
| 4 | 10 | 2 |

For every user, I want to **select the price of the order with the biggest ID**.

I can use the following query which adds additional complexity due to the nested subquery :

```
SELECT
 User.Name,
 last_user_order.Price
FROM User
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT Price, UserId FROM Order
   ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1
) AS last_user_order ON last_user_order.UserId = User.Id
```

There exist many questions here where the column to be selected is the same than the one being ordered. Hence, it is possible to use `MAX` in the first `SELECT` statement to avoid a subquery. Is it possible to avoid a subquery in my case?

Comment: What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: @Akina MySQL 5.7

Comment: What are your reasons?

Comment: *I can use the following query* It must fail due to "unknown column last_user_order.UserId".

Comment: The query you "can" use doesn't seem to give you what you say you want..

Comment: On 5.7 there is no solution without subquery. But use it in output list, not in FROM.

Comment: Can you really have an order for 2 separate userids? - order 1 has userid 1 and 2.

Comment: @Akina edited the query. Output lists with GROUP_CONCAT? Can't do that, the data will be further processed by a CRM

Comment: *edited the query* Edited query will skip the price for `'David'`. For to use this technique you need in LATERAL join which is not supported by your MySQL version.

Comment: can you give of the create and insert queries for this example? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For every user, I want to select the price of the order with the biggest ID.

That looks like:

```
SELECT
  u.*,
  o.Price,
FROM 
  User u
  INNER JOIN Order o ON u.ID = o.UserID
  INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT MAX(ID) as OrderID FROM Order GROUP BY UserId
  ) maxO ON o.Id = maxO.OrderId
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT User.Name,
       ( SELECT Order.Price
         FROM Order
         WHERE Order.UserId = User.Id
         ORDER BY Order.Id DESC LIMIT 1 ) LastPrice
FROM User;
```